# Im trying to define this but when I run the program I get an E0FError

Tags: python

It puts I have an error in the `input()` line.

```
def intro():
print("\t\t\t\t**********************")
print("\t\t\t\tBANK MANAGEMENT SYSTEM")
print("\t\t\t\t**********************")
print("\t\t\t\tBrought To You By:")
print("\t\t\t\tcode-projects.org")
input()
```

Comment: You have declared the function, you have to "call it" or use it. Try doing `myinput = intro()` at the end

Comment: Please add the correct scopes - maybe problem lays in them

Comment: Unindented Python code doesn't make sense and cannot be run.

Answer (score 0):

Python relies on indentation. The correct way of writing it is:

```
def intro():
    print("\t\t\t\t**********************")
    print("\t\t\t\tBANK MANAGEMENT SYSTEM")
    print("\t\t\t\t**********************")
    print("\t\t\t\tBrought To You By:")
    print("\t\t\t\tcode-projects.org")
    input()

intro()
```

Also, don't forget to call the function.